# Shell set environment variables for command

Tags: macos, command-line, environment-variables

I want to run a program in Terminal and set its environment variables. According to my research one can do this using:

```
VARIABLE="value" VARIABLE2="value2" run_program
```

Now I'd like to set a variety of variables using a configuration file. Indeed, I could inject variables into the active shell using:

```
. program_variables.config
```

I then can use `echo $VARIABLE` in the terminal.

Anyway, when I now run

```
. program_variables.config run_program
```

I cannot access the variables within the program. I also tried separating the two parts with `;` and `&&`.

After thinking about what's happening there I had the following ideas:

```
cat program_variables.config | xargs run_program
cat program_variables.config | tr -d '\n' run_program
```

and a few more.

I didn't write the called program myself so I cannot change the behavior how variables are read.

Any ideas how I output the file as if I would have written its content in the shell myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables are set only in the current scope, to make them visible in a program that is called or after a source (e.g. `. file`) you need to export them.

Thus program_variables.config should be

```
export VARIABLE="value" 
export VARIABLE2="value2"
```

Then just run the executable,

This can all be in one script to run the executable

```
#!/bin/sh
export VARIABLE="value" 
export VARIABLE2="value2"
run_program
```

Save this file and make it executable.
Then just use the name os this file as the program

Comment: I cannot put everything in a shell script, because the config file path is a variable itself and everything is called using a CI. But adding `extern` to the variables enables me to use  `. program_variables.config && run_program` which is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, my need was simple which was to set my credentials as environment variables only for the current session of my cli so I did put all my secrets in a shell script and tried to ran it but none of my environment variables ever showed up in my echo statement, below are the steps i followed

1. Create a simple my_credentials.sh file
2. Export all the environment variables in there like `export VARNAME="value"`
3. Save the file (you can use any editor of your choice)
4. Open terminal and launch your shell script
5. Try to do `echo $VARNAME` and my value wasn't printed because I was doing a silly mistake (I don't know why though)

**Wrong Command:** `sh /Users/me/myShellDir/my_shell.sh`
**Correct Way  :** `. /Users/me/myShellDir/my_shell.sh**`